# Program doesn't work when I give more than 6 values as input

Tags: matlab

I have 2 vectors, `x` and `y`. `x` is input vector and `y` is output. It works as long as `x` has at most 6 values. With 7 it doesn't work anymore.

I have tried it using 7, 8, and many more values. It always gives an error of NaN. It works perfectly with 6.

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
y = 3 + x.^2 + normrnd(0,0.4,size(x));
alp = 0.005;
eps = 1.e-5;
w = LinearFuncModified(x,y,alp,eps,2); 

function w=LinearFunc(x,y,alp,eps,upto)

%w = [15.8205 32.0654 24.6452];
w=zeros(1,upto+1);
[m,n] = size(x);
yh= zeros(1,n);
yh= w(1) + yh;
iter_yh=1;
while iter_yh<=upto
    yh = w(iter_yh+1)*(x.^iter_yh) + yh;
    iter_yh=iter_yh+1;
end
dj=zeros(1,upto+1);
Transx = x'    
iter = 1;
err=1;
loss =3;
while err > eps
    j(iter) = 0.5/n*sum((y-yh).^2);
    pred_err = yh - y;
    dj(1) = sum(pred_err)/n;
    iter_dj=1;
    while iter_dj<=upto
        dj(iter_dj+1)=(pred_err*(Transx.^iter_dj))/n;
        iter_dj=iter_dj+1;
    end
    err = norm(alp*dj);
    w = w-alp*dj;
    yh= zeros(1,n);   
    disp("w");
    disp(w);
    yh= w(1) + yh;
    iter_yh=1;
    while iter_yh<=upto
        yh = w(iter_yh+1)*(x.^iter_yh) + yh;
        iter_yh=iter_yh+1;
    end
    iter=iter+1;
end    
plot(x,y,'-rs')
hold on
plot(x,yh,'-o')
hold off
end
```

Even with N inputs it should give the correct values of `w`, But it gives NaN instead.

There are 4 vectors: 
`x` which is input and

`y` which is given output,

`yh` which is trying to produce `y` as close as it can be, and

`w` which contains "upto" +1 elements.

`yh` totally depends on `w` and `x`, I made `w` a vector of zeros. now y is a given formula depends on x. so i need to get w to be as close to the `3 0 4` (in this case) as they can be and to do that , i am calculating error between `yh` and `y` at every iteration and using that error I'm updating my `w` values, which will update my `yh` values and so on. The point is, if it works with 6 , why it isnt working with 7 or more?

Comment: With 7 values in `x`, `err` increases, rather than decrease. If you want more help, you'll have to explain what it is that your code is supposed to do. I don't recognize what it is that it's computing.

Comment: @desertnaut Sorry , i m new to this. Okay i will edit

Comment: This question tends to go into the direction: please debug my code for me. Without knowing the idea behind your code its quite difficult as Cris already pointed out. So as you want help you need to include the source of your code otherwise it is more than challenging to do so.

Comment: I recommend that you step through your code line by line, examining the values of the variables and seeing if they match your expectations. I don’t see anything special that would happen at 7 elements, but your equations are likely wrong, leading to an unstable iteration. Watch `err`increase at each loop iteration!